# Como colocar um show more dentro de uma tabela/formulario?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Olá bom dia galera tenho um website wordpress, e o que quero fazer hoje é adicionar um botão/texto antes do enviar de uma tabela já existente, para que caso o usuário clique no botão/texto apareça uma outra tabela que irá aparecer um questionário com cerca de 10 campos tipo texto, para preenchimento.

Utilizo o contact form.
Agradeço desde já.

No caso ao clicar naquelas palavras aparece-se o segundo questionário.

Este é o form:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Jovem vc tem uma tabela que o cara vai preencher ai quando ele clicar em enviar vai aparecer outra tabela para ele preencher mais 10 campos?? Qual o sentido disso?

Comment: Seria uma tabela para preenchimento opcional, porque iria acelerar o pensamento da minha equipe de vendas hoje.

Comment: E não seria quando ele clicar em enviar, seria um texto avisando o cliente que tem mais uma tabela mais por preenchimento opcional, mas que aceleraria o cliente!

Comment: Obrigado Hugo resolveu já.

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Accordion-Slider-Style-jQuery-Form-Wizard-Plugin-Formalize/